# Android Facebook Loginbutton NPE : Argument 'context' cannot be null

Tags: android, fragment, facebook-login

I am working on a project which integrated 
`com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton`
.I put it in a fragment and worked fine in past weeks. But suddenly, from yesterday, it's not working. I mean, I could not add this fragment just because the facebook loginbutton is there. I promise that I haven't change either the XML file or the code or logic. 
I doubt if it's because the APP_ID expired or something, so I added another app in the facebook developer console, and changed all the configurations. However, it doesn't help. 
I've attached the exception stack here:

```
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800): java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'context' cannot be null
    06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:76)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(Utility.java:594)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.java:757)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.java:732)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.newLogger(AppEventsLogger.java:400)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.logButtonCreated(FacebookButtonBase.java:225)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.onAttachedToWindow(FacebookButtonBase.java:136)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.onAttachedToWindow(LoginButton.java:452)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14514)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4348)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
06-17 11:14:46.056: E/AndroidRuntime(20800):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4059)
```

Expecting some hints. Appreciate ahead.

BTW, I followed the [Quick Start](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1801329063436994/?platform=android) to configure, and it WAS working well.

Comment: post gradle.......

Comment: @WaqarYounis The gradle followed the instruction of Quick Start, nothing special. And I've not changed anything in gradle recently.

Comment: try this gradle.. dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.0'
}

Comment: @WaqarYounis Thank you for prompt reply. I tried this as well and it's still not working.

Comment: Finally I found a duplicate question, and they've prompted a solution. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878370/argument-context-cannot-be-null